# template to transform html code

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, templates, ejs

I write a simple  program which is really unreadable. At first, I didn't know how to use template so I decide, in spite of that, to write html code inside my node.js code.
(solved)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

I usually have a project structure like:

- lib
- node_modules
- public (This is where the CSS and page JS goes)
- routes
- views (This is where you put your EJS templates)
- app.js

In your package.json make sure you have included ejs

```
"ejs": "*"
```

In app.js (assuming you use express)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var routes = require("./routes/routes.js");
//Other setup code
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Here is an example HTTP route
app.get('/home', routes.view_page);

//Other Server code
```

And then in routes.js

```
exports.view_page = function (req,res){
    var customMessage = "Hello, Node is awesome";
    res.render("view", {
       msg:customMessage
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your .ejs file is fine, this is a very minimal express server that works with your example:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var customMessage = "My Message";
  res.render('view.ejs', {msg:customMessage });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

then use your `view.ejs` and put it in the sub-folder `views/`